# How to use special characters in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following package:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MyPackage is
        function Somefunction return varchar2 is
        begin
            return 'some text with special characters like é or è';
        end;
    end package;
```

The package compiles however when executed, the text returned doesn't include the special characters:

```
    some text with special characters like � or �
```

I'm using PL/SQL allround automation and, as far as I know, it's configured to use UTF-8 charset:

[image]

**Unicode** is also enabled as can be seen in the screenshot [here](https://i.ibb.co/CBFQk6V/Capture.png).

And running the following query:

```
    select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

return:

```
    AL32UTF8
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: That's for the encoding to save text to files. Do you have UTF8 or unicode enabled under Options (I think...)? And do you have NLS_LANG set in your OS?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for your comment. Unicode is enabled as can bee seen in the screenshot here :  https://ibb.co/Q9GM2kY Do you know how to set NLS_LANG please ? My DB is in AWS clowd and I don't have access to the OS.

Comment: The NLS_LANG is set in the client OS, not the server; [this might be helpful](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html).

Comment: @AlexPoole Awesome ! thank you very much. Added NLS_LANG in the client OS and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as per @AlexPoole comments :

Add the following environment variable in Windows :

NLS_LANG : LANGUAGE_COUNTRY.UTF8